# Can we crop the input activations to match the dimensions of output as mentioned in the ResNet Paper

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, torch, resnet

I was trying to implement Resnet from scratch in python with numpy. While individual layers work perfect. I am currently stuck between conv2_3 and conv3_1 layers where the conv3_1 layer with 1x1, 128 filter downsamples the input of 56x56 to 28x28 with the stride of 2. I am currently building 152 layer one

[image: ResNet Architecture]

The part that I cant figure out is when I apply this expression

```
output_width = (input_width - filter_width + (2 * pad) ) / stride + 1
```

in this case it turns out to be (56-1+(2*0)) / 2 + 1 = 28.5 which is bigger than required dimension. The only way out I feel is to crop the input image (activation map) which I am not sure about since this may result in depletion of image information. Any idea how other libraries like tensorflow, caffe, torch are doing this ?